# ./gradlew: No such file or directory bitbucket android image

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm newbie in bitbucket pipeline and I'm following these steps in: https://bitbucket.org/blog/automate-publishing-your-android-application-with-bitbucket-pipelines-and-gradle to deploy using the android image.

But when I trying to deploy in my bitbucket pipeline repo, returns this error message : './gradlew: No such file or directory '

below my 'bitbucket-pipelines.yml'

```
definitions:
  caches:
    npm: ~/.npm
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:

        - step:
            name: Build
            image: bitbucketpipelines/android-ci-image
            caches:
              - gradle
            script:
              - ls
              - echo "$SIGNING_JKS_FILE" | base64 -d > android-signing-keystore.jks
              - ./gradlew app:assembleRelease
            artifacts:
              - app/build/outputs/**
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Tks

Answer (score 1):

This means you are missing some **gradle wrapper** files on your repository. You will need to add `gradlew` and the folder `gradle/wrapper/` to your repository. Check your `.gitignore` to see if it is currently being ignored. These files are mandatory on the repository if you want to use a pipeline. If you don't have that file and folder locally, you can follow this steps to generate the wrapper:

- Make sure you have gradle installed on your machine (e.g. on Mac OSX)

> brew install gradle

- After that you can generate the wrapper files with this command:

> gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.5

Replace 6.5 with whichever gradle version you use on your project. You can check it on the file `gradle-wrapper.properties` on the **distributionUrl**.

Comment: Thanks for your support @vitor-fernandes

One more thing that I dont get it, this image that I'm using 'bitbucketpipelines/android-ci-image' shouldn't come with this already configured?

Comment: @Prosofsky a bit late to reply to this, sorry. The gradle wrapper is generated for each project according to its settings, precisely because the project can be using a different gradle version. So this can't be part of the image, as it wouldn't work for any project. Did my previous answer solve your issue?